# Why isn't this File Upload drag/drop working, I copied CodePen code exactly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On this [testing page](http://gdoot.com/testing.php), I have everything copied from the codepen below, but when I click my box (or drag/drop), nothing happens (i.e. when i click, the choose file box should come up).

Does anyone see the issue?  I even copied that same Jquery script calls that the code pen uses (for jquery and jquery-ui) so I'm at a loss.

NOTE: I copied the HTML and CSS as "compiled."  I don't think that should matter either way, but figured I'd mention it.

```
Code Pen: http://codepen.io/SomnusHermeticus/pen/wHKyq
```

Comment: Have you tried using the page as HTML5? I.e. setting Doctype and HTML tags to;
```<!DOCTYPE html><html>```

Comment: I made sure that was there now but still not working

Comment: I'd also check you're CSS is present (it's currently giving a page 404 instead of the correct file)

Comment: That was an unnecessary CSS file, sorry about that. I removed it.

Comment: I highly doubt this is the problem, but you have one random extra `</div>` on the page.

Comment: Not a problem, I'd say it's something in you're javascript. I wasn't able to get it to error but tried a copy and paste of the Code Pen into the source and it works.

I'd also remove all of the html encoded characters and replace them with the correct characters... ie line 24 of the JS has ```&lt;``` rather than ```<```. There's also a few more ```&gt;``` and ```&amp;``` floating around too. All of which would prevent it from working.

Comment: Are you seeing &lt; in line 24 of MY javascript?  because I'm seeing "<".  Just want to make sure I'm looking in the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently all less than, greater than and ampersands are being converted into html encoded values. So `<` is returned as `&lt;`, `>` as `&gt;` and `&` as `&amp;`.

If you replace those with the correct values (i.e. `< , > , &` rather than encoded values the script works straight away.

Comment: Hi, I'm obviously missing something so I apologize in advance, but when I view source or my original code, I'm seeing >, not &lt;.  So I'm not sure what you mean by "< is returned as &lt;".  Where/how exactly are you seeing &lt;?

Comment: If that's the case you've got something that's converting the source code into HTML encoded values when you're saving your source code.

If you use a browsers developer tools you can see this in the code as served to the browser clear as day (though it's resolving to valid Javascript so it's not throwing a Javascript error).